# Is there any plastic wrapping service at the Stockholm Arlanda Airport?

Tags: luggage, arn

Is there any plastic luggage wrapping service at Stockholm Arlanda (`ARN`) airport?

And in that case what is the cost and location?

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of research I found that there is something called BagPort which offers "[WrapPort](http://www.bagport.se/cms_en/index.php?page=WrapPort)" service at Arlanda airport.

It is located in terminal 5 and has a flat price of 70 SEK per bag.

I found a phone number as well; +46-(0)8-797 62 28

BagPort is an umbrella name for a number of services, WrapPort is one but also includes things like baggage storage and lockers. The above phone number is to BagPort and not directly to the WrapPort service.